# how to insert a substring in a string with a index from a list

Tags: python, indexing, insert

I have a string and a list of number

```
s = 'x(4+1) + 4(x+1)+5+(x+1) = x(4+1) +5(x+1)+6+(x+1)'
```

and

```
[1, 10, 18, 27, 35, 43]
```

I want to insert `'*'` sign in the string with the given index value from the above list
means that I want to insert `'*'` in the 1st index of the string and then in the 10th index of the string and and it should add `'*'` according to the list of index value
I should

I don't want to delete any substring from the main string.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this. What this does is it loops for every character in your `string` variable `s` then puts it in a list, then once it's a list you can loop through your `list` of indexes and perform a `.insert()` function as you can see `.insert(index,data)`. Then do a `.join()` method to simply join all the characters.

```
l = [1, 10, 18, 27, 35, 43]

s = 'x(4+1) + 4(x+1)+5+(x+1) = x(4+1) +5(x+1)+6+(x+1)'

#loops for every character outputs a list of characters from your s variable
s = [ch for ch in s]#list comprehension


for idx in l:
    s.insert(idx,'*')


print("-----")
output = ''.join(s)
print(output)
```

Here is the output I tried.

```
-----
x*(4+1) + *4(x+1)+*5+(x+1) *= x(4+1*) +5(x+*1)+6+(x+1)
[Finished in 0.4s]
```

You might wonder what this does `s = [ch for ch in s]` this just loops for every character then outputs a list of characters from your variable `s`

This is what it looks like

```
['x', '(', '4', '+', '1', ')', ' ', '+', ' ', '4', '(', 'x', '+', '1', ')', '+', '5', '+', '(', 'x', '+', '1', ')', ' ', '=', ' ', 'x', '(', '4', '+', '1', ')', ' ', '+', '5', '(', 'x', '+', '1', ')', '+', '6', '+', '(', 'x', '+', '1', ')']
```